# Не могу в html добавить картинку с рабочего стола

Tags: java, html, изображения, png

Пытаюсь добавить картинку в html которая хранится у меня на ПК.
Сервер локальный http://localhost:8080
Пытался добавить с помощью примерно такой строки

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/qwe/Desktop/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B.png">
```

Прочитал, что нужно копирнуть эту картинку в папку с проектом, тоже не помогло, перекопировал её почти в каждую папку с проектом, не сработало, может у кого есть опыт работы с подобным?

Answer (score 1):

Картинка должна находиться в той же директории что и исполняющий файл. (В Вашем случаи скорее всего. index.php или index.html) тогда и путь src будет от него ити. 
например: `<img src="picture.png" alt=picture>`

Comment: А от чего зависит где эта исполняющая директория?
У мене проект на java с библиотекой thymleafe(Которая я так понимаю является главенствующей в плане html в этом проекте)

Comment: Там где у тебя находиться главный файл, то место и есть корнем сайта